# Make sure app.config from console project copies to bin folder of web project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, app-config

I have inherited a project that has one solution with a number of projects:

- Utility A - console application
- Utiltiy B - console application
- Commons C - shared by other projects
- Web App D - provides administrative and support functions

Now, D references some code in A and B, meaning that `A.exe` and `B.exe` are copied to the bin folder of D. However, other processes occasionally need to directly invoke `A.exe` and `B.exe`. They can't be called directly from `D\bin`, because that folder just contains the `.exe`, not the `app.config` files.

The previous workaround was deploying A, B, and D to different destinations, with `A.exe.config` and `B.exe.config` deployed only within their own folders. I'd like to get away from having 3 different deployments when it could be just one, but I'm not sure how to do it. I have tried fiddling with various 'build actions' and 'copy to output' options, but nothing seems to work.

How can I make Visual Studio copy the `A\app.config` to `D\A.exe.config`? Ideally, without a post-build script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom deployments I've always has to rely on post-build scripts to do it right (and, unfortunately, they're not as good as they are in C++).

Another thing I have done is to set up the projects so that the build output is in the same location for all projects (Respecting Debug & Release, of course), and then add the config files to their respective solutions and change the "Copy To Output" property of the config files to "Copy if Newer".  This would ensure everything ended up in the same place, with the dependencies, and you wouldn't need a post-build script.

Comment: I had considered both options, but I was hoping for a better way. This will eventually need to be integrated into a larger package / deployment process and the more of it that VS does automatically, the better. Having everything deployed together to the same folder might work, but I haven't tried it yet, and I'm slightly worried about having multiple projects build into the same destination.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, I understand your concern - they do not actually *build* in the same directory, but the output is placed in that directory (as a property of the project).  Standard behaviour of Visual Studio is to copy dependencies you have referenced.  If your projects have their dependencies set up correctly (Project `D` depends on projects `A` and `B`), then they are built *first*.  Whether or not during `D`'s compilation they are copied again is anyones' guess, but it shouldn't matter - unless you have something esoteric going on.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, and as a side note, the output directory is set up to a custom location for *all* projects rather than it being a "oh, copy everything to *this* projects location".  This means that the final deployment directory is an amalgamation of all project outputs and bears no resemblance to their own build directories.

Comment: You're correct that the projects will build in order, but the package / deployment steps are what I'm concerned about. I'll have to have three different deployment steps, with D going first, then A and B deploying into the bin folder of D (overwriting the `.exe` files as necessary). It still feels messy but, yeah this should work.

Comment: @p.s.w.g yeah - unfortunately without rolling up your sleeves and writing some custom post-build scripts (which as I mentioned earlier are nowhere near as flexible as their C++ counterparts), you're stuck with the output directory.  Why Microsoft decided to reduce the build functionality in C# compared to C++ is anybodies guess. (and by reduced functionality, I mean that we can easily use macros in output directories under C++, but not so much in C#)